# sprite-kit game running on nodejs

Tags: ios, node.js, sprite-kit

I'm very confused about how to create a true multiplayer game using sprite kit. What I mean by "true multiplayer" is that players connect to a server and not share the same game screen (like an rpg).

The problem is, I can't find any tutorials on this, every tutorial is for games like candy crush where there's a connection to a server, but the game runs on the device. The server is just used to access data, or save/update game progress.

My question is specifically: how do I have some server provide the "world" for a game, where players can connect and each have their own camera, and do their own individual tasks. Is this how multiplayer games work, or am I missing the point?

if I'm not missing the point, do I have to use a specific type of server? (in other words, since the game is written using sprite-kit, something that can communicate with sprite-kit?) or can any server (like node) work?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking doing something like the game Destiny. If that is the case, you are going to have to design your own classes. To put something like that into a nutshell, you would probably have to use a similar principal as LOD (level of detail for graphics). Meaning only draw in other players within a certain range of the user. I would venture to guess that this can be done but a lot would depend on the network connection, information passed back and forth and the iOS processor speed.

The standard features included in the GameKit framework are:

> Game Center offers a centralized game service that connects players to each other. Game Center implements many different features:
>
> Friends allow players to create anonymous online personas. Users connect to Game Center and interact with other players through an alias. Players can set status messages as well as mark other players as friends.
>
> Multiplayer allows your game to create network matches that connect players through Game Center. Players can invite their friends or be connected to anonymous players. Most importantly, players can receive invitations to join a match even when your game is not running. Your game is running on each device and the instances of your game exchange match and voice data with each other.
>
> Turn-Based Gaming provides store-and-forward network match infrastructure where the match is played out over a series of discrete turns. This kind of match can be played without requiring all of the players to be connected to Game Center simultaneously.
>
> Leaderboards allow your game to store and fetch player scores from Game Center.
>
> Achievements provide the ability to track a player’s accomplishments in your game.
>
> Challenges allow a player to challenge other players to complete an achievement or to beat a leaderboard score.

Comment: but if theres a server that is hosting the game, then the server can take care of just drawing players where they appear, rather than each device (iPhone) calculate how far someone else is from each other right?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad- Not sure what the best approach would be here and I don't think there is one size fits all answer to your question. Yes, the server could draw but then you have to have the server deliver that content to the device. If the device draws it really only needs to know what to draw and where. Each approach has pros and cons. I am sure there is also approach #3, 4, 5 and so on. Whatever approach you think is best, you WILL need some sort of cutoff point for drawing content unless your "world" is a very small one.